# Real-time print issue in Rust loop

Tags: rust

Im making a function in rust where it needs to print some text with multiple colors and it also needs to overwrite the previous printed color.
This code:

```rust
use core::time;
use std::thread::sleep;
use colored::Colorize;
fn rainbow(text:&str, secs:u64){
    let rts = [text.red(), text.yellow(), text.green(), text.blue(), text.purple()];
    println!("{}", rts[0]);
    for _ in 0..secs {
        for i in 0..5 {
            print!("\r{}", rts[i]);
            sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(200));
        }
    }
}
```

doesn't actually do what i want, It prints the text after the for loop is finished instead of printing it in real time.

Comment: stdout is almost certainly line buffered and `\r` is not considered a newline for that purpose. Use `std::io::stdout().flush()` as mentioned in the linked answer to force what you've `print!`-ed to be sent to the terminal immediately instead of sitting in the buffer.